How to set custombutton default text?
i created a custom button control.
the class code is inherited from a button.
the problem is that in the class code i set the text to "REC" but when i drag the custom button control in form1 designer from the toolbox the default text is custombutton1.
custom button text is by default custombutton1 and not REC
i want to make that when i drag the button from the toolbox the default text will be "REC".
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CB
{
    public enum ButtonAlignment
    {
        Center,
        Left,
        Right,
        TopLeft,
        TopRight,
        BottomLeft,
        BottomRight
    }

    public class CustomButton : Button
    {
        private bool _DisplayFocusCues = true;
        private Image _originalImage;
        private Image _clickImage;
        private Size _lastImageSize;

        [Category("Layout")]
        [Description("Sets the initial alignment of the button within its parent container.")]
        public ButtonAlignment InitialAlignment { get; set; } = ButtonAlignment.Left;

        public CustomButton()
        {
            this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            this.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            this.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
            this.DisplayFocusCues = false;

            _originalImage = ResizeImage(Properties.Resources.pngimg_com___buttons_PNG152, 160,160);
            this.Size = new Size(160, 160);
            this.Image = _originalImage;
            this.Text = "REC";
            _clickImage = CreateClickImage(_originalImage);
            _lastImageSize = _originalImage.Size;
        }

        protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnParentChanged(e);
            AlignButton(); // Align button when added to a parent container
        }

        private void AlignButton()
        {
            if (this.Parent == null) return;

            int parentWidth = this.Parent.ClientSize.Width;
            int parentHeight = this.Parent.ClientSize.Height;

            switch (InitialAlignment)
            {
                case ButtonAlignment.Center:
                    this.Left = (parentWidth - this.Width) / 2;
                    this.Top = (parentHeight - this.Height) / 2;
                    break;
                case ButtonAlignment.Left:
                    this.Left = 0;
                    this.Top = (parentHeight - this.Height) / 2;
                    break;
                case ButtonAlignment.Right:
                    this.Left = parentWidth - this.Width;
                    this.Top = (parentHeight - this.Height) / 2;
                    break;
                case ButtonAlignment.TopLeft:
                    this.Left = 0;
                    this.Top = 0;
                    break;
                case ButtonAlignment.TopRight:
                    this.Left = parentWidth - this.Width;
                    this.Top = 0;
                    break;
                case ButtonAlignment.BottomLeft:
                    this.Left = 0;
                    this.Top = parentHeight - this.Height;
                    break;
                case ButtonAlignment.BottomRight:
                    this.Left = parentWidth - this.Width;
                    this.Top = parentHeight - this.Height;
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);

            this.Image = ResizeImage(_originalImage, this.Width, this.Height);
            _clickImage = CreateClickImage(this.Image);
        }

        protected override bool ShowFocusCues => _DisplayFocusCues;

        public bool DisplayFocusCues
        {
            get { return _DisplayFocusCues; }
            set { _DisplayFocusCues = value; }
        }

        public new Image Image
        {
            get { return base.Image; }
            set { base.Image = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        {
            base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
            if (_clickImage != null)
                this.Image = _clickImage;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
            this.Image = ResizeImage(_originalImage, this.Width, this.Height);
        }

        private Image ResizeImage(Image originalImage, int width, int height)
        {
            if (originalImage == null)
                return null;

            Bitmap resizedImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
            {
                gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gfx.DrawImage(originalImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
            }
            return resizedImage;
        }

        private Image CreateClickImage(Image original)
        {
            if (original == null)
                return null;

            Bitmap clickedImage = new Bitmap(original);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(clickedImage))
            {
                float brightness = 0.8f;
                float[][] ptsArray =
                {
                    new float[] {brightness, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {0, brightness, 0, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, brightness, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                    new float[] {0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0, 1}
                };
                ColorMatrix clrMatrix = new ColorMatrix(ptsArray);
                ImageAttributes imgAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
                imgAttributes.SetColorMatrix(clrMatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
                g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, clickedImage.Width, clickedImage.Height), 0, 0, original.Width, original.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttributes);
            }
            return clickedImage;
        }
    }
}

what i have tried so far is to Override the Text property to set the default value:
[DefaultValue("REC")]
public override string Text
{
    get => base.Text;
    set => base.Text = value;
}

public CustomButton()
{
    this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    this.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
    this.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
    this.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
    this.DisplayFocusCues = false;

    _originalImage = ResizeImage(Properties.Resources.pngimg_com___buttons_PNG152, 160, 160);
    this.Size = new Size(160, 160);
    this.Image = _originalImage;

    // Set the default text here
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text) || this.Text.StartsWith("customButton"))
    {
        this.Text = "REC";
    }

    _clickImage = CreateClickImage(_originalImage);
    _lastImageSize = _originalImage.Size;
}


but it didn't change anything.  still same problem.
